# Dynamic th:attr definition for multiple attributes in one html element with thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to generalize form fields for a form. I want to have different `parsley.js` validation requirements. There are 2 non-standard attributes that I want to dynamically append to the input field: `required` and `data-parsley-range`. An example of a simple html without thymeleaf would be:

```html
<input type=text required data-parsley-range=[1,100] />
```

I've tried the following with thymeleaf:

```html
<input class="form-control" fieldType="text" th:attr="required=${field.isRequired ? 'required' : null}" 
th:attr="data-parsley-range=${field.validStringLengthMin ? [${field.validStringLengthMin},${field.validStringLengthMax}] : null}"/>
```

But I've got an error that `th:attr` is defined multiple times.

So my question is: How can I define multiple attributes with help of `th:attr` in a single html element?

My additional question is: How can I conditionally place the attributes? For example I don't want to write `required='required'` at all if I can avoid it, same applies to the range.

Answer (score 31):

The straight solution is to use a comma `,` to separate multiple attributes.

```html
<input th:attr="required=${field.isRequired ? 'required' : null}, data-parsley-range=${field.validStringLengthMin ? [${field.validStringLengthMin},${field.validStringLengthMax}] : null}" />
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep attributes separately for better reading purposes, you can use `th:attrappend`:

```html
<input th:attr="required=${field.isRequired ? 'required' : null}" 
th:attrappend="data-parsley-range=${field.validStringLengthMin ? [${field.validStringLengthMin},${field.validStringLengthMax}] : null}" />
```

Comment: For conditional attributes, I haven't tried this. But this should work I guess. `th:attr="${field.isRequired ? 'required=required' : ''}" th:attrappend="${field.validStringLengthMin ? 'data-parsley-range='[${field.validStringLengthMin},${field.validStringLengthMax}] : ''}"`

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I actually found a pretty cool package for thymeleaf data attrs: https://github.com/mxab/thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.  I cannot get it working the way you described in your comment though.  Anytime I place the attribute name within the condition, I get errors.